# "mostly, only X" vs. "most X"

Tags: comparison

Please take a look at the following two sentences from an LSAT:

1. For the most part, only government-sponsored research investigates agricultural techniques that do not use commercial products.
2. Most if not all government-sponsored research investigates agricultural techniques that do not use commercial products.

I can tell a main difference among others is that "most" in **2.** specifies the subject scope while "most" in **1.** comprises an adverbial that modifies the whole sentence. But what does **1.** tries to refer to by "for the most part"—part of what?

I would really appreciate it if someone could help. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example 1, the statement says that only government research investigates techniques without commercial products. It qualifies the statement with "for the most part", meaning there may be exceptions, but what follows is mostly true.

The statement is saying, in effect, that all non-government research makes use of commercial products, maybe with some exceptions.

"For the most part" doesn't refer to part of something, it's just an idiom that means "mostly".
[Collins Dictionary "for the most part"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-the-most-part)

> phrase: For the most part means mostly or usually.